# iOS NSURLConnection, No Response found

Tags: ios, iphone, soap, delegates, nsurlconnection

i have a problem in `NSURLConnection` with SOAP, it works properly in the all app classes, but in one specific class it doesn't work, once i call `[connection start];` the app don't call the call back functions (delegate functions) and i'm sure that i'm running inside the main thread and the request it right, i really need help, thanks.
the code is:

```
if(!webData)
    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                         "<soap12:Body>\n"
                         "<ActivateUser xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<UserID>%@</UserID>\n"
                         "<MelarityNo>%@</MelarityNo>\n"
                         "<Phone>%@</Phone>\n"
                         "<Name>%@</Name>\n"
                         "<Personal>%@</Personal>\n"
                         "<Rank>%@</Rank>\n"
                         "</ActivateUser>\n"
                         "</soap12:Body>\n"
                         "</soap12:Envelope>\n", @"", self.policeManID, self.policeManPhoneNum, @"", self.policeManPersonalID,@""];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link here.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[req addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ActivateUser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[req addValue:msgLen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if(con)
    con = nil;
con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[con start];
```

Comment: did you set these delegates in your header file NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

Comment: and implemented all necessary callbacks ??

Comment: No, but it works fine without them in other classes !!!

Comment: Show us the delegate methods that you have.

Comment: -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"خطأ في الأتصال" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"حسناً" otherButtonTitles:@"حاول مرة أخرى", nil];
    [alert show];
}

Comment: if you are trying to do that in background thread then you wont get the delegates get triggered. you have to do some more coding to get it work in the background.

Comment: No, i need it to run in the foreground, but the call back functions doesn't executed !!

Comment: if you put an NSlog after con like this: NSLog(@"connection = %@",con); this con is nil or not?

Comment: connection = <NSURLConnection: 0x176a8bd0> { request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x17577f50> { URL: http:link/FinesServices.asmx } }

Comment: I think there are problems with the link

Comment: @llario,if any problem occured in URL then your connection:didFailWithError NSURLConnection delegate method will call.

Comment: i think that the problem is with the NSURLConnection as i tried to load google.com but the same problem occurred !!! any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that is happening because the delegate of your NSURLConnection is released before NSURLConnection has the time to call these methods. I can't tell for sure without seeing the whole picture, but you have to see when the delegate gets released...

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure this to right solution but the bug arise may be like this.

Space doesn't default if have space change to

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link%20here.asmx"];
```